# Exclude where clause field if empty?

Tags: mysql

Is there a function for this example:

I have 3 fields in a `where` clause:

```
where field1 = ? AND field2 = ? AND field3 = ?
```

is there a way to make it so that if the value is `null`, exclude this from the search field? say for example field1 is empty, instead of search `field1 = empty`, you just exclude `field1` from the search result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
WHERE (@value1 IS NULL OR field1 = @value1) 
  AND (@value2 IS NULL OR field2 = @value2) 
  AND (@value3 IS NULL OR field3 = @value3)
```

**Explanation:**

If the parameter @value1 is passed null, it won't search against field1.

If you don't want to search against the field if that field is empty, you can do:

```
WHERE (field1='' OR field1 = @value1) 
  AND (field2='' OR field2 = @value2) 
  AND (field3='' OR field3 = @value3)
```

Comment: That makes more sense